# Why does a downvote change the daily reputation even when the user has not counted upvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

Let's suppose a user has reached the 200 daily rep. Every further upvote is not considered because the 200 daily rep has already been achieved.

But if that user has a downvote and no more upvotes after that, the reputation is decreased by 2 points.

So, my question is: shouldn't the system compensate the downvote with an upvote that hasn't been counted?

Comment: Haha, somebody touched a button there apparently :) I think the system recalculates once in a while so it should correct itself. You can check http://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation and see what the actual sum is ( it tends to be more up-to-date than the actual counter display)

Comment: @percusse It doesn't happen to me, but I've noticed it in Harish Kumar's rep on Feb 5. BTW: How to run that query?

Comment: It happened to me once, IIRC. :(

Comment: @egreg I'm surprised you would notice. :)

Comment: Why would anyone with rep counted in kilos care about 2 points more ore less? o.O

Comment: @clemens it was just a question... It didn't happen to me, BTW, as you can read in the comments above.

Comment: @karlkoeller I'm just wondering… a few hundred or even thousand rep more or less really don't make any difference for many of us

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sadly this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), even though it sucks.

Votes are accounted for at the time of casting, rather than at the end of the day. The only voting excluded from the per-day reputation cap of 200 are bounties and answer acceptance (+15).

Reference:

- [What if I hit the daily rep cap and THEN get downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70158/168244)
- [Downvote after hitting rep limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109027/168244)

Comment: So, unfortunately, it is "by-design" and nothing can be done...

Comment: You say "Votes are accounted for at the time of casting, rather than at the end of the day". Couldn't one account for votes (internally) at the end of the day (so keeping more info), while still showing the current "snapshot"?

Comment: Ah sorry, already proposed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109027/downvote-after-hitting-rep-limit#comment281412_109029

Comment: Also, note that there are users who profit from a related feature: If you have only 1 rep and get +1-1 on a Q, you end with 4 rep. If you get -1+1, you end with 6 rep.

Answer (score 8):

Not an answer but an extended comment on your observations.

The situation you've described -- losing 2 rep points due to a downvote, with the downvote counting against the maximum possible daily rep total -- becomes *even worse* in the event of an "un-upvote", i.e., a reversal of a previous upvote -- *even if the unupvote is quickly reversed*.

Consider the following screenshot (from today's rep count):

[image]

Notice how the unupvote costs 10 rep points, not just 2 points. (In case anyone cares: [The query in question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280011/5001) was posted back in Nov. 2015. My answer was the only one that was provided, and up until today both the query and my answer had only ever attracted one upvote each. Not a "hot" posting, for sure!) Interestingly, within a minute after the unupvote occurred, somebody -- for all I know, the very same person who had just unupvoted my answer; who knows, maybe it was a fat-fingers problem all along -- *upvoted* the very same answer. Unfortunately, the net effect of these seemingly offsetting votes is that I'm stuck at a maximum of 205 points for today, not the 215 points I would have earned if the unupvote hadn't occurred. :-(

Comment: This is even worse...